# Is the water damage on my floor joists serious?

Tags: water, basement, kitchens, floor

relatively new homeowner here tackling repairs and remodel on a 1920's home. Slightly handy but not afraid to leave it to the pros when it's beyond my ability. Is this bad water damage? I'm guessing the fridge line or something busted at some point as the spot sits right below the kitchen and fridge. I have a basement dehumidifier. No known direct impact of this. Is it something I should worry about? Also, bear with me - this is an old house, I'm sure I'll be back with more questions.

[image]

Comment: Does the wood feel moist or soft?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.

Comment: @crip659 as long as the source of the water has been fixed!

Answer (score 4):

You can't really detect damage from the surface appearance unless it's *really* far gone. The damage will be hidden, such as between lumber connections and behind sheathing. This doesn't usually occur from a single incident, though, or even from multiple incidents with time between. Wood needs to *remain* moist for rot to take hold--for months or years.

Do a simple penetration force test. Press a screwdriver or similar tool into the wood. Does it go in easily? Does anything crumble off? If not, it's probably still solid enough to do its job.